# Метод, чтобы присвоить 0, если поле textbox пустое

Tags: c#, textbox

Есть 4 поля текстбокс. Нужно создать какой-то метод, чтобы присваивал `textbox.Text=0` пустому полю. Если писать всё через `if else`, то получается целая гора кода. Некрасиво.

Comment: WinForms? Используйте `NumericUpDown` для ввода чисел вместо `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через обработчик события:

```
private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Text == "")
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Подпиши его на все боксы.

Взял отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902882/how-to-enter-a-default-value-when-a-textbox-is-empty